# Finding the expected value for hypergeometric probability distribution

Tags: probability

So far I have come to the term $ E(X)= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{s!(N-s)!(N-n)!n!}{(s-k)!(k-1)!(N-s-n+k)!(n-k)!N!} $ for the expected value of the hypergeometric probability distribution. According to WolframAlpha this sum does indeed evaluate to $n \dfrac {s} {N} $ which is the result I want to achieve.

I have no clue how to simplify this sum to this result! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to simplify the sum. Instead note that
$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i}
$$
where $X_i$ is an indicator random variable for the event that the ith draw is a success. Then we note that
$$
EX_i = P(X_i=1)= \frac{s}{N} = EX_1
$$
since the sequence of random variables $(X_1,\dotsc, X_{N})$ is exhangeable i.e. the joint distribution is invariant under permutatation of indices.
So
$$
EX=\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i=n\frac{s}{N}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why the expected value of $X_i$ is the same as the probability of $X_i=1$ and why that is equal to $s/N$?